# On ruby on rails got Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest while create_index and import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

**Gem I am Using**

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model', github: 'elastic/elasticsearch-rails', branch: 'master'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', github: 'elastic/elasticsearch-rails', branch: 'master'
```

**GEM FILE LOCK FOR VERSION**

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails.git
  revision: 82d799e910add123f2d95d8700ab607ba682a478
  branch: master
  specs:
    elasticsearch-model (7.0.0)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (> 1)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-rails (7.0.0)
```

**STEP I FOLLOW**

```
1) index_name = MODEL.index_name
2) MODEL.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
3) MODEL.__elasticsearch__.import
```

**I Got Following Error For each Record.**

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: type is missing;3: type is missing;4: type is missing;5: type is missing;6....
```

SO anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version  of elastic you are using, before 6.X you need to give the types while creating the index, more info here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/removal-of-types.html

Comment: I am using elasticsearch: stable 6.8.7

Comment: @can you try adding a type in your index request?

Comment: how can I add type? actually I am just beginner with this . i need to add in search query?

Comment: in your index request, after index name, like POST /my-index-name/my-index-type, I am not familiar with ruby code, but if you can share your index create request, I may be able to look at suggest where exactly you need to add that

Comment: you are using 5kype? add me ronakabhattrz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212404/discussion-between-ronak-bhatt-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).